# C++ object declaration is being called abstract

Tags: c++

For some reason I am getting this error that wasn't showing up before. The error is stating that object of abstract type InitializeState is not allowed.  However, i wasn't having this issue before, and I didn't really make any changes to either files.
Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef InitializeState_h
#define InitializeState_h
#include "State.h"
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"


class InitializeState : public State{
    public:
        void Load(sf::RenderWindow*);
        //void Load();
        void Handling(SEngine* gameEng);
        void Paint(SEngine* gameEng);
        void Update(SEngine* gameEng);
        void TidyUp();
        void Halt();
        void Continue();
        static InitializeState* Initialize(){
            return &gameStart;
        }


    protected:
        InitializeState() {}

    private:
        static InitializeState gameStart;
};


#endif
```

Here is the c++ file where the error is occurring:

```
#include "InitializeState.h"
#include "State.h"
#include "SEngine.h"

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>



InitializeState InitializeState::gameStart;

void InitializeState::Load(sf::RenderWindow* window){
    rwindow = window;
    rwindow->create(sf::VideoMode(200,200), "Working");
};

void InitializeState::Handling(SEngine* gameEng){

};

void InitializeState::Paint(SEngine* gameEng){


};

void InitializeState::Update(SEngine* gameEng){

};

void InitializeState::Continue(){
};

void InitializeState::Halt(){
};
```

The fifth line of code, InitializeState InitializeState::gameStart;, is where the error is occurring.

Here is the error window:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: 2D Game, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  SEngine.cpp
1>c:\users\brandon\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\2d game\2d game\sengine.cpp(26): error C2660: 'State::Handling' : function does not take 1 arguments
1>  Main.cpp
1>  InitializeState.cpp
1>c:\users\brandon\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\2d game\2d game\initializestate.cpp(9): error C2259: 'InitializeState' : cannot instantiate abstract class
1>          due to following members:
1>          'void State::Handling(void)' : is abstract
1>          c:\users\brandon\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\2d game\2d game\state.h(14) : see declaration of 'State::Handling'
1>          'void State::Paint(void)' : is abstract
1>          c:\users\brandon\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\2d game\2d game\state.h(15) : see declaration of 'State::Paint'
1>          'void State::Update(void)' : is abstract
1>          c:\users\brandon\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\2d game\2d game\state.h(16) : see declaration of 'State::Update'
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: "object of abstract type InitializeState is not allowed" just like i said at the top of the post.

Comment: What compiler is this? The output is typically more verbose like stating why the object is abstract (as in "you forgot to implement method X")

Comment: Visual Studio Express 2010, and it says that methods in its inherited class were abstract, but they were always like that even before the error started happening.

Comment: Post the `Output`-Window message word by word, not the `Error List`-Window message

Comment: the override of the functions Handling,Update, Paint have different signature in InitializeState. In state they don't take any arguments.

Comment: Updated my post. You are lacking a virtual dtor here too. I would really suggest learning C++ first. And yes C++ is not easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you implement

```
void State::Handling(void) override;
void State::Paint(void) override;
void State::Update(void) override;
```

From the class `State` you will be fine.

And you need to use the `virtual` keyword when overriding as you are performing method hiding otherwise.

The class `State` requires you to implement the methods above regardless of any similar methods you need with different signatures like your `SEngine` parameter.

This is basic OOP knowledge you are lacking here. I suggest reading a book like Thinking in C++ 1 and 2 to gain some understanding prior to mess with an engine.

**Edit**: Another problem with your code: Your destructor must be at least virtual as you inheriting and not using the MS proprietary keyword `sealed`. You may or probably will get into some memory leaks here.

Some reading: [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

**Edit**: Added new c++11 `override` sugar, removed `virtual`. Learned something new :)

Comment: the `virtual` is unnecessary, and should be replaced by `override` if you use a recent compiler.

Comment: Actually it didn't work but it did help me identify the actual problem: apparently the methods in my State.h were modified by accident so that they were different from the classes that implemented them.  The methods in State.h had no arguments, so I just had to add them back in.

Comment: You don't need to add `virtual` when overriding. You need to add it to the member declaration in the base class. Adding it in the derived types is optional, but using `override` will let the compiler tell you if you are failing to override for whatever reason (getting the signature wrong, for example).

Comment: @juanchopanza source? Override is a Microsoft specific keyword afaik, adding it it to derived types is *not* optional as this would cause a method hiding without providing an entry in the vtable and being properly resolved. We are talking about abstract members here.

Comment: @Samuel No, `override` is a C++ special identifier. Its use is at compile time. But the main point is that you **do not** need to use the `virtual` keyword when overriding.

Comment: @juanchopanza, cool, something I must have overlooked in the c++11 standard. Thanks for the hint. I'll update my post but I have not located a source saying I can omit the virtual here.

Answer (score 0):

> The error is stating that object of abstract type InitializeState is
>   not allowed.

This typically means that some of the virtual pure function of the type's parent are not implemented in the children. Basically, you miss some functions definitions in InitializeState.

```
1>c:\users\brandon\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\2d game\2d game\initializestate.cpp(9): error C2259: 'InitializeState' : cannot instantiate abstract class
1>          due to following members:
1>          'void State::Handling(void)' : is abstract
1>          c:\users\brandon\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\2d game\2d game\state.h(14) : see declaration of 'State::Handling'
1>          'void State::Paint(void)' : is abstract
1>          c:\users\brandon\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\2d game\2d game\state.h(15) : see declaration of 'State::Paint'
1>          'void State::Update(void)' : is abstract
1>          c:\users\brandon\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\2d game\2d game\state.h(16) : see declaration of 'State::Update'
```

Here you can see the list of member functions from the State class which are missing in the InitializeState class. This is because these functions are pure virtual: they are "required" to be implemented by at least one of the child classes.

Just implement them in InitializeState and that will fix your problem.